# Questions about node.js exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading some other's code, I saw a piece of code like this

```
if ( typeof module === 'object' ) {
    module.exports = BBB;
}
```

I am wondering
1) why using if statement here
2) when using module.exports, does it mean all BBB namespace is exported

BTW, BBB is a namespace defined like

```
var BBB = {};
```

Comment: As more and more people write code that can run both on the browser and node.js (which is a very good thing, think of what it does to validation code) you'll see more and more of this kind of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the module is intended to work in both the browser and on the server side (presumably using node.js).

Creating a sort of wrapper for your module allows it to be used in a variety of javascript loaders such as AMD or RequireJS or CommonJS (used by node)

I'd also recommend looking at [umdjs/umd](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) (Universal Module Definition). This repo documents how you can create a wrapper for your module so that it will work in every environment you target.

---

Lastly, you can sort of think of `module.exports` like a return value of a function. When someone imports the module, the export is what is given to them.

If this is used

```
// bbb.js
module.exports = BBB;
```

When the module is required using (for example)

```
// otherfile.js
var BBB = require('./bbb');
```

`BBB` will match the exported object.

Check out the [node.js module docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for more general help.

Answer (score 1):

it is to detect what environment you are in, module exists in node, but not in the browser without browserify or the like

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the author is creating a module that may not necessarily be consumed in a CommonJS enviorment, but still is offering support for it.

The CommonJS standard defines a few free variables, `require`, `exports`, and `module`. `module` must be an Object.

So when the author is checking that `module` is of type `object`, they are essentialy checking for CommonJS support, they are then assigning `module.exports` to `BBB`, so that when a consumer `require`'s their module `BBB` is returned. I won't go into the details of CommonJS but you can check out the [standard](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJShttp://) for more info.

**Why would I check for CommonJS support?**

Because your code is intended for use in multiple enviornments/packagers. For example Browserify, and Webpack use the CommonJS standard to package code for use in the browser. But when creating an API for the browser, one should assume that consumers may not be using CommonJS, therefore `module` will not be defined and assigning a value to `module.exports` will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

1) This checks if you are using this code on the server side (NodeJS).

2) Yes, all BBB namespace is exported

Here are all necessary information: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/